# How to create a local database for MYSQL workbench?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to create  a local database on my home-computer for MYSQL workbench?

This server is only for my own use. Not to the outside community.

Comment: Yes, it is very possible and I have done it.  MySQL is open source, so you can just download the free community edition and get started.  You would be able to "see" the database from your local machine, if you plan to do any development work there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download XAMPP on your machine and install it. (Windows)
After successful installation, you will be able to see an icon on your toolbar. 
Click on it and start Apache, MySQL and if anything you need. 
Open browser, type : localhost/phpmyadmmin 
This will give you an GUI to manage databases locally on your machine. XAMPP basically provides you local server.

Comment: For Ubuntu:
https://techtunes007.wordpress.com/2014/07/30/how-to-install-xampp-for-linux-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts/

Answer (score 1):

If this is what you are looking for, after creating a database in MySQL from your local machine, then that you could access the database through MySQL workbench as a local instance. It asks you to authenticate based on your MySQL conf though. Just the normal way!

Answer (score 1):

You can download WAMP (**A**pache, **M**ysql, **P**HP) server on **W**indows.

Then add new connection in workbench.

```
host:127.0.0.1
username:root
password:<Empty>
```